# file upload (php) two warnings

Tags: php

I am working on small page where I update MySQL records via PHP page, all the functionality is well working but I constantly get warnings for an Undefined array.
Here are the warnings:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 11
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 11
Warning: Undefined array key "file" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 22
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\edit.php on line 22
```

I was looking at many topics like this but did not manage to fix my own one...
Here is the code of edit.php

```
include 'db.php';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
}
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','doc','xlsx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        }
```

I have also a pcs of HTML for that in <form:

```
<form name="update_user" method="post" action="edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<tr>
                <td>Нов сертификат:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" ></td>
</tr>
```

I have a feeling that I missed something very simple.

----- update -------
here is my full code: in one file I put php with the html

```
// include database connection file
include_once("config.php");
//тук стартирам за фаил ъплоад
// Include the database configuration file
include 'db.php';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
}
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','doc','xlsx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        }
// край на фаил ъплоад

// Check if form is submitted for user update, then redirect to homepage after update
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $toolnr=$_POST['toolnr'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $toolname=$_POST['toolname'];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'];
    $usedat=$_POST['usedat'];
    $owner=$_POST['owner'];
    $calibrated=$_POST['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration=$_POST['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors=$_POST['vendors'];
    
    // update user data
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET toolnr='$toolnr',status='$status',toolname='$toolname',serial='$serial',usedat='$usedat',owner='$owner',calibrated='$calibrated',nextcalibration='$nextcalibration', vendors='$vendors', file_name = '$fileName' WHERE id='$id'");
    // Redirect to homepage to display updated user in list
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<?php
// Display selected user data based on id
// Getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];
// Fetech user data based on id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tools WHERE id=$id");
while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $toolnr = $user_data['toolnr'];
    $status = $user_data['status'];
    $toolname = $user_data['toolname'];
    $serial = $user_data['serial'];
    $usedat = $user_data['usedat'];
    $owner = $user_data['owner'];
    $calibrated = $user_data['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration = $user_data['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors = $user_data['vendors'];
    $momenten = $user_data['file_name'];
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Актуализация</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <center> <img src="logo-ottobock.png" alt="OttobockLogo"> </center>
    <hr> <br>
    <center> <img src="notification.png" alt="Warning"> </center>
    <center> <i> <p style="color:red;"> В момента работите с най-високо ниво на достъп, моля бъдете внимателни. <br> Всички направени от Вас промени са необратими. <p> </i> </center>
</head>
<body>
    <br/><br/>
    <center> <form name="update_user" method="post" action="edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <table border="0" class="table table-striped" >
            <tr>
                <td>Номер</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="toolnr" class="form-control" value=<?php echo $toolnr;?>></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Статус</td>
                <td>
                <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control" required>
    <?php
        include "dbConn.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT status FROM tools WHERE id=$id UNION SELECT currentstatus FROM statuses");  

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['status'] ."'>" .$data['status'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Найменование</td>
                <td><input type="text"  name="toolname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $toolname;?>"></td>
            </tr> <br>
            <tr>
                <td>Сериен номер</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="serial" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $serial;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Локация</td>
                <td> 
                <select name="usedat" id="usedat" class="form-control" required>
    <?php
        include "dbConn.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT usedat FROM tools WHERE id=$id UNION SELECT locations From whereused");  
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['usedat'] ."'>" .$data['usedat'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Отговорник</td>
                <td>
                <select name="owner" id="owner" class="form-control"  required>
    <?php
        include "dbConn.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT owner FROM tools WHERE id=$id UNION SELECT responsiblepersons From responsibles");  
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['owner'] ."'>" .$data['owner'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Калибриран на:</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="calibrated" class="form-control" value=<?php echo $calibrated;?>></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Следваща</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="nextcalibration" class="form-control"  value=<?php echo $nextcalibration;?>></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Сертификат</td>
                <td><?php echo "<a target = '_blank' href='http://10.171.2.15/crud/uploads/$momenten'> Свали </a>";?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Нов сертификат:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="file" ></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Калибрира се при</td>
                <td>
                <select name="vendors" id="vendors" class="form-control" required>
    <?php
        include "dbConn.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT vendors FROM tools WHERE id=$id UNION SELECT vendoren FROM vendors");  
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['vendors'] ."'>" .$data['vendors'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update"  class="btn btn-success" value="Запис">
                 <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger" >Отказ</a>  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> </center>
</body>
```

Comment: please add all the code that is relevant - the code you shared is incomplete

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you **cannot** have a `form` at that particular location within an HTML table. The form **must** either be wholly contained within a single table-cell (`td`) or the entire table must be wholly contained within the form!

Comment: You should move all code which deals with `$_FILES` and `$_POST` inside `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
}` , otherwise you can easily get warnings during the page loading (before the form has been submitted), if the PHP code is in the same script as the HTML form.

Comment: Post updated with full code. I have one edit.php inside together PHP with HTML
Please see the update.

Comment: @ADyson, I have tried but is not working... please see full code in the update

Comment: `I have tried`...where? What you've posted doesn't show you trying what I suggested. That `if` statement contains precisely nothing. There is lots of code which requires the existence of $_FILES and/or $_POST, yet most of it is outside any block which checks for its existence. If your code tries to use something which doesn't exist, you'll get an error warning exactly like the ones you're seeing.

Comment: P.S. You don't even have a `name="submit"` in your form, so it would need to be `if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){ }`

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the stringent support. Now everything is working well after your guidance. Updating the post with the final code.

Comment: Great. But please don't edit the _question_ to show your solution. That belongs in the _answers_ section, below these comments. See also [answer] and the [tour] to ensure you understand how the question and answer format works here. Also, if you post your solution as an answer, it is more prominent in searches (because the question appears to the search engine as having a solution) and you can get upvotes on that from other users who find it helpful. That can't happen if you confusingly put working code into the question.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250889/discussion-between-azim-feta-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting working code:
final-fixed code (only php part). The problem was that the part of the code responsible for file upload was out of the `if statement`

```
<?php

// include database connection file
include_once("config.php");

// Check if form is submitted for user update, then redirect to homepage after update
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $toolnr=$_POST['toolnr'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $toolname=$_POST['toolname'];
    $serial=$_POST['serial'];
    $usedat=$_POST['usedat'];
    $owner=$_POST['owner'];
    $calibrated=$_POST['calibrated'];
    $nextcalibration=$_POST['nextcalibration'];
    $vendors=$_POST['vendors'];
    
// Include the database configuration file
include 'db.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){

    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','doc','xlsx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    }
    }
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
        }

    // update user data
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET toolnr='$toolnr',status='$status',toolname='$toolname',serial='$serial',usedat='$usedat',owner='$owner',calibrated='$calibrated',nextcalibration='$nextcalibration', vendors='$vendors', file_name = '$fileName' WHERE id='$id'");
    // Redirect to homepage to display updated user in list
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```